# how to use jwt.sign() in node.js

Tags: node.js, jwt

I started learning jwt in node.js. But I'm stuck here

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let token = jwt.sign({name:"Sachin"},"secret" ,{expiresIn: '2000s'});
console.log("generated token", token);
```

This returning different-different signature part of token on multiple calls but the payload and secret key is same in every calls. So how does this happen?

Also when I try to verified them using copy-paste then also it gives error "invalid token"

```
jwt.verify(token,"secret",(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Verified "+result);
```

What is happening here ?

token 1 generating is =>

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiU2FjaGluIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE0NTQxOTk0fQ.O518KGK_m47Mw2fBBKDdABZUFGxXzYShrMoYQnLJQwM
```

token 2 generating is =>

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiU2FjaGluIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE0NTQyMDA4fQ.FwY_XJ0ryAZzuJ1EpaUkqVNTNutkA63t0Vkie468zkM
```

Comment: the additional question why verification fails can't be answered based on the given information. I checked both tokens on jwt.io and they can't be verified with the secret "secret". I guess you played a lot and probably a one point generated these with a different secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because every time you generate a token a new expiration time (`exp`) is calculated (current time + 2000s in your example) and the expiration time is part of the payload. Every change in the header or payload causes a change of the signature, because the signture is a hash of header and payload.

`jwt.sign` by default adds a `iat` (issued at claim), that has the same effect as the `exp` (in regards to changing the payload everytime when you generate a token). Both timestamps have a resolution of 1 second (Unix epoch time format).

Your payload will look like this:

```
{
  "name": "Sachin",
  "iat": 1614540008
  "exp": 1614542008
}
```

When your goal is (for the sake of learning things) to generate exactly identical tokens in consecutive calls, you have to avoid all kinds of timestamps (`iat`, `exp`, `nbf`(not before)).

This can be achieved with the `{noTimestamp:true}`option in the call:

```
jwt.sign(payload, "secret", {noTimestamp:true})
```

You can check the generated tokens on https://jwt.io/ to see what's inside.

Comment: I tried it by removing the {expiresIn: '2000s'} field but it also doesn't work. It still returning different-different token.

Comment: I guess there's also a "iat" (issued at timestamp), same effect as "exp". If not, please show your token in the question, it's difficult to talk about something without actually seeing it.

Comment: I tried using a field iat but it also doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean with "tried using..."? The tokens you show in your question contain a IAT and that is automatically generated and makes every token different. As said before, got to jwt.io to inspect your token and see the difference.

Comment: that's the question that how to avoid changing of token on same secret key and same payload

Comment: can you give me the exact code of sign and generating jwt

Comment: I added and option to avoid timestamps. See my edited answer.

Comment: Your goal should not be the exact same tokens, only that you can verify them with the secret.

Comment: @Joe  I assume that the OP just starts learning this and tries to figure out how it works. In any realistic use case you would certainly handle it different.

Comment: @jps {noTimestamp:true} it works now for signing. Thanks . But verification of token still doesn't work. Please help me in this also

Comment: My problem was solved actually I passed the "token" instead of token in jwt.verify().